# What does sheet = sheetList.FirstOrDefault(ws => ws.Name == string.Format(name, i)); mean?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am working on an Excel add-in that has the following line of code:

```
sheet = sheetList.FirstOrDefault(ws => ws.Name == string.Format(name, i));
```

What does it mean? More specifically I can't figure out what `ws => ws.Name` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to provide `First` sheet from `sheetList` whose `Name` = `string.Format(name, i)`.

Its like

```
Sheet sheet = null;
foreach(Sheet ws in sheetList)
{
    if (ws.Name == string.Format(name, i))
    {
       sheet = ws;
       break;
    }
}
```

sheet = sheetList.FirstOrDefault(ws => ws.Name == string.Format(name, i));

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` is an extension method that works on any `IEnumerable<T>`. It's purpose it to yield the first item matching the given `Func<T, bool>`, which is equivalent of a predicate.

What this predicate will do is attempt to match the item's name, `ws.Name`, to another string, which is returned from `string.Format(name, i)`.

What it does is equivalent to:

```
foreach (var sheet in sheetList)
{
    var formattedSheetName = string.Format(name, i);
    if (sheet.Name == formattedSheetName)
    {
        return sheet;
    }
}
```